# file upload with cakephp maldicore admin plugin

Tags: php, cakephp, file-upload

I am using Maldicore admin plugin, and I have a problem with the file upload.

It basically boils down to that:

Calling **$this->request->data** at the controller only gives the following data

```
Array
(
    [Spice] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Black Pepper Seeds
            [image] => black pepper seeds.jpg
        )

)
```

When most of the online sources list attributes like ['tmp_name'], ['error'], and etc. What am I missing out here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you did not make your form a multi-part / file form, in CakePHP you can do it this way:

```
$this->Form->create('Model', array('type' => 'file'));
```

If you don't use the right form type the file appears usually like what you pasted.